# Calculating limit of $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!} \vert k - n \vert$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to show that for each $n \in \mathbb N$ it holds that
$$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!} \vert k - n \vert = 2n \frac{n^n}{n!}.$$
But I have absolutely no idea how to do that. I tried to split the series like this: 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!} \vert k - n \vert = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \frac{n^k}{k!}(n - k) + \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!} (k - n)$$
Now I want to show that $\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \frac{n^k}{k!}(n - k) = \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!} (k - n) = n \frac{n^n}{n!}$ holds. But I got no idea how to achieve that. I tried to use induction but things became pretty messy and I don't think it will work like that. On the other hand I got the idea that it might have to do with $\exp$ or binomial coefficients but I don't see where I can facilitate that. I would appreciate some hints :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split further:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{n^k}{k!}(n-k) + \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{k!}(k-n) &= \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!} - \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} \frac{n^k}{(k-1)!} + \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{(k-1)!} - \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!} \\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!} - \sum_{k = 0}^{n-2} \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!} + \sum_{k = n}^{\infty} \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!} - \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!} \\
&= \frac{n^n}{(n-1)!} + \frac{n^{n+1}}{n!} \\
&= 2n\frac{n^n}{n!}.
\end{align}